# How to build projects in parallel using Eclipse/CDT (not parallel compiling!)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have several projects which all rely on a basic library. Now when I change a header file in this basic library I have to rebuild all dependent projects. Currently Eclipse/CDT builds one project after another. How can I build all these projects in parallel?

Please note that I already use the -j (parallel compiling) option for each project. But this is not enough because:

1. there are really a lot of CPU's available (for most projects more than source files) and
2. due to parallel compiling the linking takes *much* longer than compiling and (to my knowledge) can not use multi-threading.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/303/ It's the perfect excuse, why change it? ;)

Comment: Can all of the projects that depend on your library be in turn made dependencies for a dummy project which could then be built in parallel?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Xeo: Can't! Wait! Any longer!

Comment: @vpit3833: The point is, that eclipse compiles and links project 1, when this is finished than project 2, than project 3 ... And when it's compiling I have ~40% load (thanks to -j but still not 100% because often there are not enough source files to keep all cores busy) and when it's linking ~5% load (15 idle cores ...). So the overall load is like ~15%. But my naive mind wants it like 6 times faster with 100% load :D

Comment: Do you HAVE to compile in eclipse? Perhaps if you compiled from the command line the basic library, then you could kick off multiple threads simply using the basic library object (some makefile magic?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the current version of Eclipse CDT can build projects in parallel, but you can achieve the same effect by having an Eclipse CDT Makefile project which builds multiple binaries (libraries and executables).

A simple way to generate such project is by using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) with [Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) generator. Then if you specify `/usr/bin/make -j<n>` as a build command, where `n` is the number of parallel jobs in Project Properties, it will build your targets (not only source files) in parallel.

Comment: We moved from eclipse managed builds to cmake used as generator, then from makefiles to ninja - both decisions improved built times significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Project Properties > C++ Build > Behaviour > Enable Parallel Build